# Trying to create pivot and return date values

Tags: sql

Trying to create a pivot table in sql to return date values, never done this before but I've run into a wall and only return 'Null' values. Is it possible to return date values? Appreciate any help! Query below:

```
SELECT SYS_ID, JOB_ID, 
[JOB_OPENED] AS A, [JOB_ENDED] AS B, [ROW_CONSTRUCTED] AS C, [SITE_CONSTRUCTED] AS D, [CONTRACT_ASBUILT_COMPLETE] AS E, [FIBER_ASBUILT_COMPLETE] AS F, [COAX_ASBUILT_COMPLETE] AS G, [JOB_RECONCILED] AS H
FROM 
(SELECT COMPLETION_DATE,  DATE_MILESTONE_NAME, SYS_ID, JOB_ID 

FROM EIMS.JOB_MILESTONES_RV) AS RV
PIVOT
(MAX(COMPLETION_DATE)
FOR DATE_MILESTONE_NAME IN ([JOB_OPENED], [JOB_ENDED], [ROW_CONSTRUCTED], [SITE_CONSTRUCTED], [CONTRACT_ASBUILT_COMPLETE], [FIBER_ASBUILT_COMPLETE], [COAX_ASBUILT_COMPLETE], [JOB_RECONCILED])
) AS PivotTable
WHERE JOB_ID > 40000
AND SYS_ID = 8778
ORDER BY JOB_ID
```

this is the current table: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PwFH.jpg)

but I want it to look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnx2n.jpg)

Comment: Please, provide some details like output that you expected.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is non-standard SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT SYS_ID
      ,JOB_ID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_MILESTONE_NAME = 'JOB OPENED' THEN COMPLETION_DATE END) AS "JOB OPENED"
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_MILESTONE_NAME = 'JOB ENDED' THEN COMPLETION_DATE END) AS "JOB ENDED"
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_MILESTONE_NAME = 'SITE CONSTRUCTED' THEN COMPLETION_DATE END) AS "SITE CONSTRUCTED"
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY SYS_ID
        ,JOB_ID
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!